# How to access a file in a mapped network drive with PHP & IIS 7

Tags: php, iis-7

I'm trying to read a file on a mapped network drive(shared folder on a Windows XP machine) through a PHP code & using IIS 7 (and it is set up on a windows 7 machine). When I run my code I get an Access denied error, "failed to open stream: Permission denied". I'm using below code to access the file:

```
$handle = fopen('\\\\servername\\sharedfolder\\test.txt', "r");
```

I checked permissions on the host machine(running XP). Under the sharing tab, it is only showing `share this folder on the network check box` , and `Allow network users to change my files` check boxes and both are checked. Windows firewall is off for the time being. 
Any help to fix this issue is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the problem SOLUTION: Created a new user account with password. In IIS Manager, changed IIS Anonymous Authentication from IUSR to the new user account and gave the same password. Windows XP sharing has been set to 'Everyone' with Read permission